# Win32 Capturing child Window messages in parent window

Tags: winapi, mfc, parent-child, childwindow, wndproc

In my Win32 application, a child window is created by a third party SDK.The Window creation process is transparent and I cannot associate a WndProc method with the child Window. I want to be able to capture child window messages in parent window. How can I do this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried CWnd::SubclassWindow?

Comment: You can trivially associate your own window proc with `SetWindowLong` and `GWL_WNDPROC`. You can do this for each and every window in your process.  See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633570(v=VS.85).aspx#subclassing_window

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? Or if that seems like overkill you could probably just use [SetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `GWL_WNDPROC` and define your own custom WinProc then forward to the child window.

There is a pretty good [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#subclassing_window) about it.

Comment: Hi Again, does this solution works for multi-threaded application? In my application Parent window is in main thread while child window is in separate thread. I have tried subclassing but it's not working.